# Using advanced field calculator in QGIS Python console

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, area

I am trying to calculate area using field calculator in the Python console of QGIS.

Here is the expression which I wrote.

```py
output8 = processing.runandload('qgis:advancedpythonfieldcalculator', "E:\GIS-Temp\Result\shapefile_2017\Clip1modified_2017.shp", "Area", 1, 5, 5, ' ', $geom.area(), "E:\GIS-Temp\Result\shapefile_2017\Clip2modified_2017.shp")
```

The error comes as syntax error.

Comment: $geom.area() is not suitable for python. What is geometry type of $geom? (feature, layer etc.)

Comment: Your paths are also invalid. Backslashes must be escaped or raw-formatted.

Comment: If I wish to calculate the area what formula should I write? Should it be $area() alone.

Comment: No. You should give area with QgsGeometry or etc.

Comment: output8 = processing.runandload('qgis:advancedpythonfieldcalculator', "E:\GIS-Temp\Result\shapefile_2017\Clip1modified_2017.shp", "Area", 1, 5, 5, ' ', QgsGeometry.area(), "E:\GIS-Temp\Result\shapefile_2017\Clip2modified_2017.shp"). This also gives error.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using qgis3 you should use `processing.runAndLoadResults()`

```
something = processing.runAndLoadResults("qgis:advancedpythonfieldcalculator", 
    parameters={'INPUT':'C:/GIS/data/testdata/ak_riks.shp','FIELD_NAME':'areafield',
    'FIELD_TYPE':1,'FIELD_LENGTH':10,'FIELD_PRECISION':3,'GLOBAL':'',
    'FORMULA':'value = $geom.area()','OUTPUT':'C:/GIS/data/testdata/ak_riks_witharea2.shp'})
```

Notice the forward slashes in the paths, or use raw syntax, for example: `r'C:\GIS\data\testdata\ak_riks.shp'`

A tip is to execute the tool manually then check syntax in history:
[image]

Comment: I am unable to understand that how to access this option of seeing the syntax in history. Can you explain it in detail.

Comment: After you execute the algorithm with success manually go to: Processing menu - History or Ctrl+Alt+H

Comment: In the Processing menu-History is not getting updated in my case. It stays blank even after executing any operations.

Comment: I dont know why

Comment: output8 = processing.runandload("qgis:advancedpythonfieldcalculator",{'INPUT': "E:\GIS-Temp\Result\shapefile_2017\Clip1modified_2017.shp",'FIELD_NAME':'area','FIELD_TYPE':1,'FIELD_LENGTH':10,'FIELD_PRECISION':3,'GLOBAL':'','FORMULA':'value = $geom.area()','OUTPUT':"E:\GIS-Temp\Result\shapefile_2017\Clip9modified_2017.shp"})
Error: Wrong parameter value E:\GIS-Temp\Result\shapefile_2017\Clip9modified_2017.shp for parameter OUTPUT.

Comment: You dont even read the comments or my answer. You **cant have backslashes in your path** unless you use raw syntax.

Comment: output8 = processing.runandload("qgis:advancedpythonfieldcalculator",{'INPUT': 'E:/GIS-Temp/Result/shapefile_2017/Clip1modified_2017.shp','FIELD_NAME':'area','FIELD_TYPE':1,'FIELD_LENGTH':10,'FIELD_PRECISION':3,'GLOBAL':'','FORMULA':'value = $geom.area()','OUTPUT' : 'E:/GIS-Temp/Result/shapefile_2017/Clip9modified_2017.shp'})
Error: Wrong parameter value E:/GIS-Temp/Result/shapefile_2017/Clip9modified_2017.shp for parameter OUTPUT.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112826/discussion-between-karan-gupta-and-bera).